# Update Loop in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently creating an order database system. My SQL Server is pretty limited so this may have a simple answer I haven't noticed. Is there a way to do :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

in SQL Server. I'm trying to update stock when an order is confirmed.

This is what I have so far and as you can see what it is I want in the comments. Well it's what the PHP part of my brain would do.

```
--UPDATE ORDER -- 

IF EXISTS(SELECT NAME FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE NAME ='CONFIRMED_ORDER')
   DROP PROCEDURE CONFIRMED_ORDER
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE CONFIRMED_ORDER
   @ORDERID [INT],
   @PRODUCTID [INT],
   @ORDERSTATUS [NCHAR](10),
   @STOCK [INT],
   @QUANTITY[INT],
   @CURRENTSTOCK[INT]
AS
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
      UPDATE ORDERS
      SET ORDERSTATUS = @ORDERSTATUS 
      WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID;

      IF (@ORDERSTATUS = 'Confirmed')
      BEGIN
          SET @PRODUCTID = (SELECT PRODUCTCODE 
                            FROM ORDERLINES 
                            WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID);

          /*WHILE (@PRODUCTID)
          SET @QUANTITY = SELECT QUANTITY 
                          FROM ORDERLINES 
                          WHERE ORDERID = @ORDERID AND PRODUCTCODE = @PRODUCTID;

          SET @CURRENTSTOCK = SELECT UNITSINSTOCK 
                              FROM PRODUCTS 
                              WHERE PRODUCTCODE = @PRODUCTID;

          UPDATE PRODUCTS
          SET UNITSINSTOCK = @CURRENTSTOCK - QUANTITY;*/
    END
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ERRORNO, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERRORMSG
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
END
GO
```

As I said, I'm fairly limited with SQL so any answer, even if it's to say this isn't possible would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not thinking in SQL. Why not do the whole thing with a single `update`? Using `while` in SQL usually means you're not thinking about it right. In any case, yes, T-SQL does support while cycles and cursors. It's not *that* simple, but just search for `declare cursor mssql`.

Comment: This is totally not clear -- what is WHILE(@PRODUCTID) mean?  While there are more records in products with PRODUCTID == @PRODUCTID?

Comment: to phrase it another way. You need to think in sets instead of row by row. This means you need to change your thinking to "what do I want to do to a column" instead of "what do I want to do to each row". It is a difficult paradigm shift in thinking.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - This is exactly the wrong advice to give anyone moving to SQL.  IT IS ALWAYS WRONG TO USE A CURSOR IN SQL... in every case the code can be written without a cursor OR moved to the client code.

Comment: @Hogan Well, there are legitimate use cases. It's just that this isn't one of those cases by far :D

Comment: @Luaan - I doubt it.

Comment: @Hogan There certainly are legitimate use cases for cursors - e.g. [running totals on versions < 2012](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals), Itzik Ben-Gan has alluded to several other cases where SQL Server's optimizer just doesn't handle the conversion to set-based well, and also many maintenance tasks (e.g. run some stored procedure against every database or every table).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Interesting link since the fastest performer was a non-cursor.  I'll still maintain that given a task where the set based performance is low that task should be implemented external to the DB.  DBAs don't want to admit there are tasks that shouldn't be implemented in the database tier, but (IMHO) there are --> if they can't be implemented more efficiently in the DB than in another part of the system.

Comment: @Hogan and requires SQL Server 2012. So a cursor is still the best option in multiple scenarios prior to 2012 (and some after, too). Do what you want, but I don't think I would perform this specific task outside of the database, and sometimes you can't (e.g. when it feeds another database system, or reporting tools, etc). So I will continue to argue that "no cursor in the database. ever." is a silly standpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you don't need a cycle at all. You just have to think natively in SQL, rather than trying to write the same thing as in PHP:

```
update [Products]
 set [UnitsInStock] = [UnitsInStock] - OL.[Quantity]
from [Products] P
inner join [OrderLines] OL on OL.[ProductCode] = P.[ProductCode]
where OL.[OrderId] = @OrderId
```

This will update all the "stocks" of all the products in the order in one statement.

Note that this assumes there's only one order line for each product ID - if you don't ensure there aren't duplicities, you need to change this a bit to sum all the lines of a single product ID together.

Oh, and you're mixing procedure parameters with local variables. Declare the parameters the way you do, but then do the local variable declaration after the `as`, e.g.:

```
declare 
        @STOCK [INT],
        @QUANTITY[INT],
        @CURRENTSTOCK[INT];
```

Comment: +1, I read it quickly, I answered based on each product, so missed the join.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this inside the `IF` block

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS
SET UNITSINSTOCK = UNITSINSTOCK - ISNULL(@QUANTITY,0)
WHERE PRODUCTCODE = @PRODUCTID;
```

As for the `LOOP`, you should probably create this client side...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 //call sp
```

Comment: You're missing the cycle, which is the thing the OP asks about.

Comment: @Luaan, I think the `LOOP` should probably be done on the clieet-side, from PHP in this case?

Comment: For this project there is no client side. I wouldn't of been in this predicament if there were. I'm trying to increase my knowledge of SQL Server as it is used a lot at the company I have recently started at.    Thank you for your input though.

Comment: @DavidPerry, what calls the SP?

Comment: @christiandev currently it is me in SQL Server this is purely a self study project. intending on doing it completely through SQL and then a simple client side to just called the procedures and pass parameters.